# Keep only rows for which sum is less or equal than a threshold

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data

import pandas as pd

```
pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],
             'day':[1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4],
             'value':[5,6,7,8,9,11,12,13,14],
'day_before': [4,4,4,4,4,3,3,3,3]})

id  day value   day_before
0   1   1   5   4
1   1   2   6   4
2   1   3   7   4
3   1   4   8   4
4   1   5   9   4
5   2   1   11  3
6   2   2   12  3
7   2   3   13  3
8   2   4   14  3
```

I want for each `id`, to keep only the `day`s  that are smaller or equal than the `day_before` **and** that the sum of `value` is smaller or equal than 20

The resulting dataframe is this

```
pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,1,1,2,2],
             'day':[3,4,5,3,4],
             'value':[7,8,9,13,14],
                'day_before': [4,4,4,3,3]})

id  day value   day_before
0   1   3   7   4
1   1   4   8   4
2   1   5   9   4
3   2   3   13  3
4   2   4   14  3
```

**Explanation of result**

For `id==1`:

- I am keeping the `day`s > 4
- Sum of of `value` for `day==4` is 8 -> I keep it
- Sum of of `value` for `day==4 or day==3` is 15 -> Still smaller than 20, so I keep them
- Sum of of `value` for `day==4 or day==3 or day==2` is 21 -> larger than 20 so I keep only `day==4 or day==3`

For `id==2`:

- I am keeping the `day`s > 3
- Sum of of `value` for `day==3` is 13 -> I keep it
- Sum of of `value` for `day==3 or day==2` is 25 -> larger than 20 so I keep only `day==3`

How could I do that ?

Comment: id1 day 5 shouldn't be in the output according to your logic

Comment: day 5 is larger than day 4, so I keep it, no ?

Comment: there are 2 conditions. One is the cumsum, and the other is day > day_before

Comment: OK, see update to my answer and let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a column of the values that not after "day_before", then reverse it and compute a [`groupby.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum.html). Use that to create a boolean mask with [`ge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ge.html) and perform [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
# rows with day > day_before
m1 = df['day'].gt(df['day_before'])

# reversed cumsum of the days ≤ day_before
# keep below threshold
m2 = (df.assign(val=df['value'].mask(m1))
      [::-1].groupby('id')
      ['val'].cumsum().le(20)
     )

out = df[m1|m2]
```

Output:

```
   id  day  value  day_before
2   1    3      7           4
3   1    4      8           4
4   1    5      9           4
7   2    3     13           3
8   2    4     14           3
```

Intermediates:

```
   id  day  value  day_before     m1     m2  cumsum
0   1    1      5           4  False  False    26.0
1   1    2      6           4  False  False    21.0
2   1    3      7           4  False   True    15.0
3   1    4      8           4  False   True     8.0
4   1    5      9           4   True  False     NaN
5   2    1     11           3  False  False    36.0
6   2    2     12           3  False  False    25.0
7   2    3     13           3  False   True    13.0
8   2    4     14           3   True  False     NaN
```

Comment: I dont understand why for m2 you mask for m1, since m1 means `day > day_before`

Comment: It should be `mask(~m1)`, no ?

Comment: It should be as I wrote it. The `mask` is to ignore the values after the day_before in our reversed cumsum (see the "intermediate" at the end of my answer).